# Default IEqualityComparer faster than a hand-written one for dictionary with Enum type as key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, .net-core, .net-6.0

For some odd reason, it seems a hand-written equality comparer for a specific enum is slower than the default equality comparer a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` uses.

How is that possible? Tested on .NET 6.0.

The hand-written equality comparer:

```
public class EnumEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DayOfWeek>
{
    public bool Equals(DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y) => x == y;

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] DayOfWeek obj) => obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Why would that not be possible? Using the default equality comparer is the most common scenario and obviously something that the JIT compiler can be expected to go out of its way to optimize for when using primitive types (and types backed by primitives, like enums). By contrast, ensuring your hand-crafted code runs equally efficiently (by doing things like devirtualization and avoiding calls that box at all costs) is harder, and less of a goal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert in the past Enums were treated very poorly by the default equality comparer. It was about 10 times slower than writing your own code. I'm just curious how they fixed that gap, to the point they even outperformed the former solution. Who said anything about it being not possible?

Comment: It depends on what versions you're comparing, of course, but they're doing things like aggressively inlining the methods and deferring to internal implementations with intrinsics. See, e.g., [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/6.0/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/EqualityComparer.CoreCLR.cs#L163) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/6.0/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.CoreCLR.cs#L198). (And I interpreted "how is that possible" as an incredulous statement. :P)